# Using DataProtection with a specific Key

Tags: encryption, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out how to use the new DataProtection features of .NET Core in a way that will allow me to specify my own encrypt/decrypt key. This will allow me to encrypt data outside my netcoreapp and then decrypt that data inside my netcoreapp (and visa versa).

Background:

I have database with hashed passwords and encrypted Social Security Numbers. There is an application that sits on top of this database that is written in .NET 2.0.

We are creating a new UI in ASP.NET Core that will exist at the same time as the .NET 2.O UI. Users can sign in under the old UI to do things and then turn around and sign in under the new UI and do other things.

What I've tried so far:

1. The documentation from the [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/index.html) website does not cover this scenario.
2. I found the the test [Encrypt_KnownKey()](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/8503e161d061fa230b00ba58d6801d7f906356ce/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Test/Managed/ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptorTests.cs) which uses [ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/8503e161d061fa230b00ba58d6801d7f906356ce/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/Managed/ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.cs). I believe it is using it's own key, but unfortunately it is `internal`.
3. We have converted our .NET 2.0 encryption code to .NET Core but it's a whole-bunch-of-scary and I was hoping for an out-of-the-box solution.

UPDATE:

4. My current process stores the key using Windows DPAPI, so I updated the `key-{guid}.xml` by replacing the generated Windows DPAPI encrypted key with the Windows DPAPI encrypted key from my existing system. Not surprisingly, this did not work.

It doesn't seem unreasonable to want to specify a specific key, so I'm hoping the reason I'm having issues finding the solution is my lack of knowledge of all things encrypted.